# Css-problem: font-size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a css-problem I really don't seem to understand :) I have been styling css for three years now, but I've never had this problem.

I have declared some styles in my css-file that should apply for the content of my page. This is generally the right css, but there are some exceptions, like the page_child_title. I was under the impression that if I declared a style further in my css for specific classes, these would override earlier css-declarations. well now, in this case, it is not true. When I inspect with firebug, it seems that my browser really wants to use the font-size-css of ".page a" instead of using the ".page_child_title" (and I for one do not agree with my browser). The color of ".page_child_title" is applied correctly however. Below you can find the Html and css I'm talking about.

**Html**

```
<div id="page" class="page Jobs">
    <div class="page_child">
        <a class="page_child_title" ...
```

**Style.css**

```
.page p, .page ul, .page a {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}
style.css (line 208)


.page_child_title {
    color: #006633;
    font-size: 12px;
}
style.css (line 262)
```

I have already tried replacing ".page_child_title" with ".Jobs a" but this didn't work. Then I tried declaring ".page_child_title" before ".page a", same result, so now I'm kind of stuck. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: May be problem of relationship, what's happen when you use firebug on the concerned element ?

Comment: It would seem to me that selecting an element by it's type rather than classname would be more specific. Try changing to `a.page_child_title`

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that did the trick! I do think that this is a "malfunction" with css :)

Comment: No worries, I'll post it as an answer and you can accept it :)

Comment: no malfunction. it is by design.

Comment: Then i find this a flaw in the design, since you would expect that ".page_child_title" is more specific than ".page a" (since ".page_child_title" is declared directly in the a-element).

Comment: When you read the article I have posted, this design makes totally sense.

Comment: I totally understand how the design is put together, I just feel that it could have been resolved in a better way regarding the specificity. Direct parents should be more specific instead of the more distant parent, like in my example (and how I thought it should have been). Of course, I have no idea what that would do to the speed of parsing the html etc, but I feel as if specificity could have been put together more logically. (and other people will feel different about this, so there is really no good answer or explanation to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that selecting an element by its type rather than classname would be more specific.

Try changing `.page_child_title` to `a.page_child_title`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/9g59w/).

Answer (score 2):

`.page a` is a more specific selector. Therefore its settings will be used.

This phenomenon is called **css specificity**:

http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/

`a.page_child_title { ... }` would work.

Comment: A really interesting article. I'm reading it through right now, and there are a few things in there that I didn't know yet ;) Thanks for the article!

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions,

1. http://jsfiddle.net/ErsS4/

Change `page_child_title to`

```
a.page_child_title
```

Or

1. http://jsfiddle.net/m5V8f/

This meathod is a direct statment to the element.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix should be to change your style to

```
a.page_child_title
```

I believe it has something to do with the hierarchy of css and declaring the style of `a` itself.